# Spring jpa transactions in same session not working

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions, spring-jdbc

This is my code sample

```
saveClaim(){
Claim claim = new Claim();
claim.setId(1);
claim.setName("Jhon");
claim.valid(true);
myrepo.save(claim); //first transaction
boolean response = callAnotherMicroservice(claim);
if(resp){
claim.accepted(true);
myrepo.save(claim);//third transaction 
}

# Microservice in different server
callAnotherMicroservice(claim){
    boolean resp=false;
    if(some condition check){//returns true and claim table is updated
    claim.valid(false);
    myrepo.save(claim);//second transaction
    resp = true;
    }
    return resp;
}
```

Even though I update claim table in call through another microservice. valid column gets overridden to true in my third transaction. myrepo is a interface that extends JpaRepository.

Comment: Logically that is correct , you are not resetting valid to any other state after second transaction and whatever was set to valid value at line 5 stays true and commits with third txn . Set the valid status accordingly after second txn to get the required result

Comment: valid status is set to false after second transaction. But after third trasaction it gets overridden.

Comment: true . that is because you created claim and set the claim.valid(true) and never reset afterwards. the same claim object is saved/updated with second transaction

Comment: I am pretty sure the logic would work if the condition block is modified as follows if(resp){
claim.valid(false);
claim.accepted(true);
myrepo.save(claim);//third transaction 
}